# Debug Spock tests in Intellij IDEA

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, spock

I'm running Spock tests by "Right click -> Run -> Test Name". How can I run tests in debug mode? Debug icon run tests but doesn't stop on breakpoints

Answer (score 0):

I believe it might be a bug in how the meta classes work in groovy.  I found that the break point will work if it is not on a control structure or closure.  I found the work around on the intellij forums:

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-82741

Comment: I couldn't make that work. Just adding the line `Integer.metaClass.xxx = {}` at the beginning of the test worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

I had the "same" issue (not sure if it has the same cause as for the OP)

On my side it was somehow gradle and IntelliJ IDEA related.

IDEA uses per default the gradle build system from the local system when it comes to executing and debugging groovy tests.

But there is an option to run the tests "natively" in IDEA's build system.

I have tried out the IDEA based build system setup for running groovy tests and then it worked.

Setting can be found under `Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle`

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Usually this works fine. If it doesn't, it might be a problem with your IDE and Groovy or Grails. I recommend to try with the latest version of IDEA.

Comment: How does this answer the question? This is really more of a comment.

Comment: It's an attempt to help someone solve a vague problem. With the little information provided, it's hard to do better than that. It would be better to ask this question on a mailing list or support forum.

Comment: It doesn't usually work. The debugger does not stop on breakpoints when running spock tests.

Comment: Usually works fine for me (although I don't often set a breakpoint in a spec). Debugging Groovy isn't always as smooth as debugging Java though.

Answer (score -3):

perhaps you should use RightClick -> **Debug** (Not Run)